# Can one of the outputs be always zero?

Tags: logic-gates, karnaugh-map, boolean-algebra

[image]

Now matter how many times I tried to do it again one of the output is always 0 and I don't know how to show it in gates. Is is possible or do I make any mistake?
The requirement are below:

The circuit should take 4-bit input and generate 3-bit output.
The input consists of two 2-bit binary numbers X(X1X0) and Y(Y1Y0), respectively.
The output is represented as O(O2O1O0).

The circuit is supposed to perform two basic operations based on the values of the X and Y :

- If X and Y are both odd numbers then the circuit should add X and Y and set the output O as the result of the addition operation.
- Otherwise, the system should multiply X and Y and set the output as the result of the multiplication.

Suppose the input is given as 1011. The left most two bits represents X in the form of X1X0 and the rightmost two bits represent Y as Y1Y0. Therefore, X = 10 and Y = 11. Since X is even and Y is an odd number, the numbers will be multiplied and the value of output, O, should be set to 110 (10*11 = 110).

Comment: This question reduces to : is there any case given the requested functionality, where the output is odd? Can you find such a case, or prove that one must exist, or prove that none can exist?

Comment: I don't think you've done anything wrong. A pair of odd numbers added together will always be an even number, and an even number will always have its least-significant bit = 0. A pair of even numbers multiplied together will also always produce an even number. So your result where one of your output bits is always 0 is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @brhans how to show it in gates?

Comment: No gates are required. 0 is just 0 or GND. Its a constant...

Comment: @brhans how can I create a contradiction or tautology with the available inputs which always produce 0 or 1?

Comment: If you insist on using a gate to produce a constant 0, then something like A./A will do it for you. But really, just put a 0 instead of a gate.

Comment: @brhans I need to use gates :) So you mean I can draw it according to this expression ~x1•x1•~y1•y1•~x0•x0•~y0•y0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your truth table seems correct.

Adding two odd numbers produces an even number.

Multiplying an odd number by an even number produces an even number.

Multiplying two even numbers also produces an even number.

Since the output is always even, the LSB is always zero, you can just tie it to ground and save some gates.

Comment: how can I  create a contradiction or tautology with the available inputs which always produce 0 or 1?

Comment: You can do someting like "A AND NOT A" (always 0) or "A OR NOT A" (always 1).